# Android: If app loaded from notification, doesn't show in task manager

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Not sure this is supposed to happen but to replicate:

1. Kill the app
2. Send a push notification via GCM to the app
3. Tap on the push notification (which loads the app)
4. The app then loads with the Activity set in the PendingIntent
5. Then tap the home button

Now bring up the task manager and notice the app is no longer there.

Has anyone seen this before, as it doesn't seem to happen for any other apps I've seen on the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer my own question, the reason this was happening was because the Activity I had in my PendingIntent didn't have the LAUNCHER category associated with it.

So when the Activity was loaded, it didn't actually load the entire app but just the Activity on its own.  I.e. the Activity was just loaded as a sheet "on top" of the UI.

So to fix, I just changed the PendingIntent to point to my MAIN activity, and when that was loaded, read the extras from the intent and then load the related Activity.